# Items Control and Items Template within another Items Control/Data Template

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I am trying to display an Items Control which contains another Items control representing an array of LED indicators.  The LED array and all the other data in the main Item Control is bound to an Observable collection.  I can't get the LED array to display.  I also know I'm having an issue with the IValueConverter to convert byte to brush color (the entire byte array comes in but I want it to just do one element at a time and even when I hard code the return value the LED doesn't display). I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong (I'm pretty new at all this).  Thanks in advance for any advice!

My code behind for ValueConverter

```
namespace Test
{
    public class ByteToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((byte)value == 1) ? Brushes.LightGreen : Brushes.DarkOliveGreen;
        }
    }

    class userData : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private byte[] led;
        public byte[] Led
        {    
            get { return led; }
            set
            {
                byte[] input = value;
                if (input != this.led)
                {
                    this.led = input;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }       

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
}
```

My Xaml code

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Test"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None">
    <Window.Resources>

        <src:ByteToBrushConverter x:Key="LEDConverter" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="myLedTemplate" DataType="{x:Type sys:Byte}">
            <Grid>
                <Border Height="12" Width="12" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="{Binding Led,Converter={StaticResource LEDConverter}}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="myHwTemplate">
            <Grid Margin="10,10,10,10" MinWidth="110" MinHeight="90">
               <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" >
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" x:Name="userControlNameLabel" Content="{Binding Path=name}" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" x:Name="powerLabel" Background="{Binding Path=Power, Converter={StaticResource int2color}}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Powered" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,1,5,1" />
                        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Margin="5,5,0,0">
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Led,Converter={StaticResource LEDConverter}}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myLedTemplate}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid Margin="0,60,0,0" >
            <ItemsControl Name="ssedu0ItemControl" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myHwTemplate}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here's my main code

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<userData> ssedu0LBData = new ObservableCollection<userData>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < Properties.Settings.Default.unit.Count; i++)
                ssedu0LBData.Add(new userData(Properties.Settings.Default.unit[i]));
            ssedu0ItemControl.ItemsSource = ssedu0LBData;

            for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
                ssedu0LBData[1].Led[i] = 1;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice job with this question by the way, it's a lot of code, but you included *just enough* to show all the issues. Kudos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is here:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Led,Converter={StaticResource LEDConverter}}"
```

You don't want to run the *collection* through a converter, and certainly your converter doesn't currently work on a collection. So that line should be:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Led}"
```

You would use the converter later on in the data template for that ItemsControl, when you did something like:

```
<Border BorderBrush="{Binding Path=. Converter={StaticResource LEDConverter}}"/>
```

A word of warning about your code. Changing individual elements of that array will *not* propagate to the UI. You need to use a wrapper around your `byte` that implements INPC, or just replace the whole array instead of changing individual elements.

Comment: Thank you, the array does display now and as you pointed out, my changes are not propagating to the UI.  I'm afraid I don't understand how I'm supposed to fix that.

Comment: @mkk Well, I gave you two solutions. Could you explain where you are confused in a bit more detail?

Comment: In my actual code, I am using a function that pulls individual bits out of a byte, combines and rearranges them and stuffs them into the byte array which I return and assign to the LED array in my sample code.  Wouldn't this be replacing the entire byte array at once?  But the Brush colors are still not being displayed. Actually, no colors are displaying right now, just the border around each LED element.

Comment: @mkk Change the binding on "Background" to "Path=." instead of "Path=Led". That should fix your brush issues. And yes, it sounds like you replace everything. Its just your `MainWindow` constructor *doesn't* and so I was afraid that kind of code was elsewhere as well.

Comment: @mkk No problem. Glad you got it figured out!